# Does android maps api V2 need background data enabled?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

Because the new Google Maps Android API V2 needs Google Play services, does "Background data" need to be enabled to run the map app?  I am in the habit of turning off Background data when I don't need it as it kills the battery quickly, and I wouldn't want my app to require it be enabled.

Update:  Spent a day trying to research this by:
- Installing the Android Support Library and Google Play Services SDK (oh look, there already an update to rev. 3 available).
- importing the sample code referenced at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code>.
- Getting a new maps v2 API key, and putting it in AndroidManifest.xml
- (Re)configuring the sample code, and run/debugging it.
The demo app won't run on the emulator, due to the Play Services requiring software that can't be built into the emulator, and it seems a lot of work to fix that, maybe some other time.  So I ran the demo on a Samsung Intercept with Froyo on it.  The SupportMapFragment and/or com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView code made me go off and update the Google Play services APK.  To do that, I needed to enable "Background data" (which was the original question).  After that, the app allowed me to select the various map demos, but none of them display a map.
The LogCat shows:

```
    12-04 19:50:28.937: I/(18909):  =======Chunk::PrintChunkBlckInfo   ======
    12-04 19:50:28.937: I/(18909): libGLESv1_CM_fimg.so was unloaded and GLES 1.1 API was successfully unmapped
    12-04 19:50:34.557: I/(18909): libGLESv1_CM_fimg.so was loaded and GLES 1.1 API was successfully mapped
    12-04 19:50:34.562: I/(18909):

    12-04 19:50:34.562: I/(18909): [Chunk Allocator] 1 blocks (block size:0x100000)
    12-04 19:50:34.562: I/(18909):

    12-04 19:50:34.562: I/(18909):  =======Chunk::PrintChunkBlckInfo   ======
    12-04 19:50:34.562: I/(18909):

    12-04 19:50:34.562: I/(18909): ------------------------------------------------------
    12-04 19:50:34.562: I/(18909):  [0] use flag: 1, start: 0, size: 1048576, next: 0x0 
    12-04 19:50:34.562: I/(18909):

    12-04 19:50:34.562: I/(18909): ------------------------------------------------------
    12-04 19:50:34.562: I/(18909): Total Texture Size 0 Byte 0 KB Total Texture Count 0
    12-04 19:50:34.562: I/(18909):

    12-04 19:50:34.562: I/(18909): ------------------------------------------------------
    12-04 19:50:34.937: E/(18909): glCompressedTexImage2D(0xde1, 0, 0x8b96, 32, 8, 0, 1280, 0x0x369c70);
    12-04 19:50:34.942: E/(18909): glCompressedTexImage2D(0xde1, 0, 0x8b96, 32, 8, 0, 1280, 0x0x379b90);
    12-04 19:50:34.962: E/(18909): glCompressedTexImage2D(0xde1, 0, 0x8b96, 16, 1, 0, 1040, 0x0x347ac0);
```

So now, I still don't have a definitive answer, and don't know whether the reason for the map not displaying is a problem with my key generation/insertion (nothing to indicate that in LogCat), or (more likely?) a problem with OpenGl.

Answer (score 2):

The three things need to be checked.

1. Does the device have Google services installed:

   ```
   switch (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)) {
   case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
       //Device has Google play services installed
       break;

   default:
       break;
   }
   ```
2. Does OpenGL ES 2.0 supported

   ```
   private boolean checkGL20Support(Context context) {
   EGL10 egl = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL();
   EGLDisplay display = egl.eglGetDisplay(EGL10.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

   int[] version = new int[2];
   egl.eglInitialize(display, version);

   int EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT = 4;
   int[] configAttribs = { EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 4, EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 4,
           EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 4, EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE,
           EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT, EGL10.EGL_NONE };

   EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[10];
   int[] num_config = new int[1];
   egl.eglChooseConfig(display, configAttribs, configs, 10, num_config);
   egl.eglTerminate(display);
   return num_config[0] > 0;
   }
   ```
3. Verify the API key is correct
   i.  Does the key generated through the correct debug key and package
   ii. Key generated through 'Google Maps Android API v2' **NOT** 'Google Maps API v2'[image]